# Why didn't Masaharu turn back to lifeless doll form after time-reversal magic?

Tags: nanatsuiro-drops

At the end of episode 9 of *Nanatsuiro Drops*, Masaharu revealed his identity of being Yuki to Sumomo. As Sumomo was from Retroscena, the magic inside Masaharu permanently turned him into lifeless doll form (in contrast to the walking Yuki-chan). He was rescued by Sumomo's time-reversal magic (episode 10), reverting his body to the time before Sumomo knew his identity.

However, the world around him was not reverted. In particular, Sumomo still had the knowledge/memory that Masaharu was Yuki. This is confirmed in the dialogue between the two inside Sumomo's bedroom (beginning of episode 11).

**Question:** After the time-reversal magic, why didn't Sumomo's knowing Masaharu's identity immediately turn him into a lifeless doll?